# Unable to Delete or Create a Windows Service from the DOS Command Line

Tags: windows-services

I am attempting to delete a C# based Windows Service from the DOS command line as follows:

```
sc Delete "MyService".
```

I am getting an error which says:

> "[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED: 5"
>
> "Access is Denied"

This is my own personal computer I'm attempting this on. Can anyone tell me exactly what I'm being denied from, and how to get around this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Oded: DOS - it says so in the question title :) Please Cmd.exe is not DOS.

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#?

Comment: Did you write the service yourself?  Could it still be running? Have you tried [uninstallutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run this from an elevated command prompt (i.e. Run as Administrator), in order to ensure the correct permissions.

See how to do this in the answer to "How do I run a command with elevated privileges?" on the official [Command Prompt: frequently asked questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219034706if_/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#) page.

Comment: Or just right-click the Command Prompt shortcut and pick 'Run as administrator' from the context menu.

Comment: @KennyEvitt - Sure. If you have one to click on.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Comment: @Jimenemex - thanks, updated with archive.org link.